# Terraform couldn't download GIT repository

Tags: git, terraform, terraform-template-file

I have enterprise GIT and a public repository with name "Terraform". I used below config file and also created a folder with name "jaish" under execution path. But getting error message on running init as

```
"Error downloading modules: Error loading modules: error downloading 'https://github.XXX.com/<<user>>/Terraform': XML syntax error on line 34: expected element name after <"

provider "github" {
token        = "XXXXXX"
}
module "jaish"{
  source = "https://github.xxx.com/<<user>>/Terraform"
}
```

Anything missed here?

Comment: Why are you defining a `github` provider here? That's used for managing teams and repositories etc on Github, not for downloading projects. And I think you just want to drop the `https://` prefix here. Terraform defaults to HTTPS cloning Github links but you can use the `git@github.com:hashicorp/example.git` to use SSH to clone the repo. If you're using Github Enterprise (the domain suggests so) then you need to use the [Generic Git sourcing syntax](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/sources.html#generic-git-repository)

Comment: It's enterprise only and I followed the last link you shared. So now I added this content in .tf as  "module "consul"{
  source = "git::https://github.XXX.com/user/Terraform.git"
}" and getting error as "Error downloading modules: Error loading modules: module Terraform: No Terraform configuration files found in directory: .terraform\modules\00850326e3a1a85943eb26336ebc73d7". I think I missed something for module "consul". I understood it as a sub-folder under terraform execution path....Do I need to do any extra for this module?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, it seems that you were testing with the `<<user>>` in the Github URL and not an actual legitimate user.

Comment: It has actual user there. But I just noticed that the files are already downloaded from git, the error message was showing though. Not sure what is it expecting even after downloaded from git. I added one blank .tf file in the git source downloaded path and this error gone. But I am couldn't able to link all these to what has actually missed to throw this error?

Comment: What does TF debug-level logging show? 
enable it in sh/bash:
```export TF_LOG=DEBUG
export TF_LOG_PATH=/tmp/tf.debug.txt
```

Comment: Sorry, but I am running it in Windows cmd. I will try enable it through windows command prompt.

Comment: Here it is splitted in to 2 comments "2018/04/12 16:17:36 [INFO] Terraform version: 0.11.3  3802b14260603f90c7a1faf55994dcc8933e2069
2018/04/12 16:17:36 [INFO] Go runtime version: go1.9.1
2018/04/12 16:17:36 [INFO] CLI args: []string{"D:\\JAISH\\TERRAFORM\\terraform.exe", "init"}
2018/04/12 16:17:36 [DEBUG] Attempting to open CLI config file: C:\Users\jmathews4\AppData\Roaming\terraform.rc
2018/04/12 16:17:36 [DEBUG] File doesn't exist, but doesn't need to. Ignoring."........

Comment: .........
2018/04/12 16:17:36 [INFO] CLI command args: []string{"init"}
2018/04/12 16:17:36 [DEBUG] command: loading backend config file: D:\JAISH\TERRAFORM
2018/04/12 16:17:36 [DEBUG] plugin: waiting for all plugin processes to complete...

Comment: It always looks for `terraform.rc` - that's not a problem. However, if this is the entire debug output, then you may have other issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Define your module as below (no need to specify `github` provider, and make sure you can access your github repository via ssh)

```
module "jaish"{
  source = "git@github.xxx.com:<<user>>/Terraform.git?ref=master"
}
```

Run `terraform init`, and might let me know if the error persists.

Comment: Paht "D:\JAISH\TERRAFORM" used to run terraform locally, The error shows as 


Error downloading modules: Error loading modules: error downloading 'file://D:/JAISH/TERRAFORM/git@github.XXX.com:<<user>>/Terraform.git?ref=master': source path error: CreateFile D:/JAISH/TERRAFORM/git@github.XXX.com:<<user>>/Terraform.git: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.